Are there other examples of non-human life in Dune?
In the Dune series the major characters are all human-being settlers from Old Earth, Terra.
However, seemingly the only non-human life forms that are mentioned are the plot-centric spice worms of Arrakis. Even the Freman of Arrakis are said to be descendants of Zensunni Wanderers who are supposed to be descendants of the Sunni branch of Islam, with Zen Buddhist influences.
Are there any other references to or mentions of creatures or life forms that are true 'alien life forms' and not just creatures that were brought from earth initially but have since mutated/evolved into something new and exotic?

Well, to go with sandworms, there are also sandtrout...

If we go by the movies, Paul Atriedes is clearly part-elf.

I haven't read the book in a long time, but in Dune Part 1, aren't there those little mice that take dew off their ears, or are they an example of "creatures that were brought from earth initially but have since mutated/evolved into something new and exotic?"

Also super related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102855/in-dune-did-all-life-start-on-earth?rq=1

@CaptainJamesT.Kirk - That's a dupe, not just related.

Based on the first book alone, at a minimum, Arrakis is host to hawks, bats, mice, and date palms, plus whatever was in Margot Fenring's moisture-world botanical garden.  Indeed, Paul's Fremen name, "Muad'dib", means "kangaroo mouse".

Do "thinking machines" count?
